# How to call an algorithm with various array sizes

Tags: arrays, sorting, random

I am struggling with creating a method where I can create random arrays of various sizes.

I need this because I have to test some algorithms with random arrays, and we need to report on how they do on different input sizes.

To have the different sizes, I though I could create an array of all the input sizes I wanted and loop through it an assign the values to n below but it doesn't seem to be working.

The below code compiles, but I'm not getting the different input sizes. I do however get a random array.

I have the algorithms in question in another class and they're all running fine so I won't include that here - it's just this part which is tripping me up.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
public class Array {
    static int[] randomArray(int n){
        int [] inputSize = {50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000};

        for (int i=0; i<inputSize.length; i++){
            n = inputSize[i];
        }
        int[] array = new int[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            array [j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
        }

        return array;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please, add a example of calling for Array.randomArray() and a expected result. This is more simples to undestand!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this dynamically initializing array size. What you're doing is initialization with fixed length and predefined elements.

The following code creates arrays of random size in range `0-10` where each element is in range `0-100` itself:

```
public class Main {

    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static int maxSize = 10;
    private static int maxNum = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays()));
    }

    public static int[] arrays() {
        int r = random.nextInt(maxSize);

        int[] array = new int[r];

        for (int i  = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = random.nextInt(maxNum);

        return array;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[41, 83, 41, 45, 89, 47, 61, 65, 2]
[45, 0, 11, 3, 26, 18, 8, 20]
[29, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this loop

```
    for (int i=0; i<inputSize.length; i++){
        n = inputSize[i];
    }
```

n will always be equals 500000;

You can replace this loop with Random.

```
Random random = new Random();
n = inputSize[random.nextInt(inputSize.length)];
```

So this code will assign to n random value from your `inputSize` array

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<inputSize.length; i++){
    n = inputSize[i];
}
```

`n` will have the value 500000

The solution is to put all subsequent code into that loop as well.

Edit:
However, your method will still only return a single array. Perhaps split up

```
public class Array {
    private static int [] inputSize = {50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0; i<inputSize.length; i++){
            int size = inputSize[i];
            int[] randomArray = createRandomArray(size);
            //perform your tests on randomArray
        }
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new int[] of length 'size', filled with random ints between 0-100
     **/
    private static int[] createRandomArray(int size){

        int[] array = new int[size];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            array [j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
            //or replace with a call to Random.nextInt(100) as suggested by others, for tidiness and to avoid the cast
        }


        return array;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get randomized array you need to randomize **n**. Look:

```
static int[] randomArray(){
      //sizes
      int [] inputSize = {50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000};
      //randomized size
      int n = inputSize[(int) (Math.random() * inputSize.length)];
      //array with randomized size
      int[] array = new int[n];
      //filling array with randomized array
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        array [j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
      }
      //randomized array (values + size)
      return array;
}
```

Result:

```
[59, 82, 40, 2, 34, 15, 96, 98, 73, 71, 93, 83, 37, 88, 87, 11, 44, 81, 61, 33, 99, 71, 24, 41, 50, 77, 4, 39, 34, 12, 33, 94, 92, 50, 95, 76, 92, 47, 85, 56, 97, 7, 34, 50, 67, 69, 34, 47, 22, 91, 50, 68, 81, 67, 37, 90, 72, 16, 28, 37, 97, 74, 39, 32, 66, 63, 30, 90, 61, 44, 39, 11, 84, 89, 70, 79, 88, 58, 88, 48, 89, 16, 82, 7, 17, 11, 94, 4, 22, 29, 83, 65, 21, 39, 22, 35, 87, 87, 10, 4]
```

See working in https://ideone.com/VX0CvL.

**UPDATE IN 05/12/2018:** If you need to order this result do:

```
static int[][] randomArray(){
   //sizes
   int [] inputSize = {50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000};
   //result
   int[][] result = new int[inputSize.length][];
   //randomized size
   for (int i=0; i<inputSize.length; i++){
        //define length
        int n = inputSize[i];
        //create array
        int[] array = new int[n];
        //filling array with randomized array
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            array[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
        }
        result[i] = array;
    }
    //randomized array (values + size)
    return result;
}
```

Result:

```
[88, 9, ...] # n = 50
[25, 37, 24, 35, 52, ...] # n = 100
[2, 34, 7, 17, 82, 42, 20, 57, 69, 24, ...] #n = 500
...
```

See working in https://ideone.com/BCM69F

Comment: Hi Aristofanio, thanks for your answer!
So the problem is that I need to call them in order, so that I can then print out how all of the algorithms do on the same input size. In my runner class, I have called all the algorithms along with the randomized array, I just need a way to loop through all of the array sizes for comparison purposes. Sorry that I didn't make that clear!

Comment: Ok! I will to complete this example.